DAW software intended to be used as 21st-century software
When I was 10 years old, I worked hard to buy my first computer: a Vic-20 in 1985. Since then, I have worked in IT, earned certifications, and even designed commercial websites in the 90s. Despite my experience, using digital audio workstation (DAW) software is harder than taking off a lady's underwear, and less rewarding.
Millions of people in pretty much every culture in the world use music production hardware and the DAWs that are modeled after it, so I am confident that this style of interface is great for many people. But for me, the UI style feels like an extreme prank gone wrong.
I'm on Windows. I have been using GoldWave for a couple of years, and I am 80% accustomed to it. Many aspects of using the mouse for selection are still bizarre to me, but my efficiency gets a passing grade.
I have had Audacity almost as long as I have had GoldWave, but that software is driving me crazy. It has added some cool features, like non-destructive editing, but manipulating things on the timeline is so difficult that I get destructive.
I've spent a few months trying very hard to understand and use Cakewalk from BandLab. BandLab happens to be located in Singapore, where there are many people who speak Mandarin Chinese. Learning Chinese was much easier for me than learning this software, and I speak Chinese much, much better than I can use this software. It makes me feel like an 二百五. Even the file management makes me want to punch myself in the face. A few days ago, I found that it had stored five copies of a large file in a directory I didn't create, right off the root, which I didn't want. Yesterday, all the template files disappeared, so I had to create a very, very empty new project. It was so empty that I couldn't figure out how to set up the "master" track-doohickey. I don't want to learn how to produce music; I want to edit some stupid audio files that contain speech.
Recently, I thought, "Maybe expensive software is easier to use. So I installed a bunch of demos and tried to use them: Steinberg SpectraLayers, Adobe, Waves Audio (I can't remember if they had a DAW), and I feel like I'm forgetting one.
Tangential complaint: I had to authenticate six times to install and open the software to evaluate it. Prisoners can go from cell to freedom with fewer security checks.
Some of Waves' tools produced good results, but all of the interfaces were as logical as a portable dartboard you inflate with air.
SpectraLayers may be ah-mazing, but I gave up after it crashed eight times trying to open it. Hey guys, maybe you should spend a little less time trying to stop people from pirating your software and a little more time making your software something people want to pirate.
Adobe: When Adobe makes one of the best UIs in your software category, you are doing something wrong. I was able to get things done in Audition, which is an improvement. Still, every task requires 98 clicks, and they offer 63 options for the simplest things, but a single slider bar for a multi-dimensional task. Black means white, and you say tomato, they say redFruit. If it were free, I would use it: it is better than Audacity.
DeScript: No.
OBS: I got confused by the paradigm and quit after one project, but I sensed that it might be okay if I could "get it". I'm not sure it's a DAW, though.
Ironically, I have become quite proficient with FFmpeg during this time: I routinely create filtergraphs with tens of thousands of characters.
In fact, Praat is easier to learn and use than any of these DAWs.
Overall, I want a general purpose DAW. GoldWave doesn't support VST3, so I need something that can use VST3 plug-ins. In almost every single piece of software I have personally tried since at least 1998, if the user was familiar with any other computer program, then the user could perform most tasks in an unfamiliar program. But remember the song, "One of These Things is not Like the Others"? If you were to show the audience three random software programs and Audacity, everyone would point to Audacity because you can't use it like other programs. I want a DAW that is like the others, you know?
As if my request wasn't difficult enough: I can't spend money. Look, I know a lot of people tell you how broke they are by comparing their lives to the shows they watch on Netflix and Disney Plus. That's not what I'm saying. I can't spend money on software because I already have to choose between spending money on housing, food, or healthcare. So I need free, not cheap, okay?
